# How do you say "to top off the gas tank"?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario

When pumping gas in the States, they say, "Don't top off the tank."

It seems like it's basically when your gas tank is full and you keep trying to pump gas into it. You're not supposed to do that.

How do you say "top off the tank" in Spanish? /Is there an equivalent in Spanish for this particular context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*"Llenar (el depósito / el tanque)"*, lit. "to fill the tank up",  is the verb we use for pumping gas. Sometimes we reinforce it with *"hasta arriba"* (lit. "all the way up") or *"hasta el tope / a tope"* (to the top).

To say that you want them to fill up the tank, but you do *not* want them to try to pump gas beyond that, i.e. don't top it off, you can say:

> *Lleno, por favor, pero sin pasar del tope.* → Fill it up, please, but don't top it off.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer!

Comment: In Colombia the expression "Hasta que dispare" "Until it triggers" its also used, meaning to fill until the is-full sensor trigger.